# Errror Compiling SQLCipher for IOS using openssl

Tags: ios, openssl, sqlcipher

I have a version of SQLCipher that is currently compiling correctly using Apple Common Crypto. I want to switch it to use openssl.

I've removed the security framework, and 
I've addded to `/usr/local/ssl/Release-iphoneos/include` to the "`header search path`" of the project, and 
`/usr/local/ssl/Release-iphoneos/libcrypto.a` to the "`other linker flags`" of the project

(My openssl is installed at `/usr/local/ssl/Release-iphoneos/` - I've confirmed it works ok with other programs.)

On compile I get error:

> FIPS_rand_bytes((unsigned char *)buffer, length)
>   Implicit declaration of function FIPS_rand_bytes is invalid in C99.

In `rand.h` my openssl include directory there is a int `RAND_bytes()` defined but in the openssl source code there is a macro (in `fipssyms.h`) that changes `RAND_bytes` to `FIPS_rand_bytes()`

Comment: Just wondering why you want to move to OpenSSL from Common Crypto.